# Django: safely deleting an unused table from database

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-migrations, django-database

In my django application, I used to authenticate users exploiting base *django rest framework authentication token*. Now I've switched to *Json Web Token*, but browsing my *psql* database, I've noticed the table **authtoken_token**, which was used to store the DRF *authentication token*, is still there. I'm wondering how to get rid of it. I've thought about 2 options:

1. deleting it through migration: I think this is the correct and safer way to proceed, but in my **migrations** directory inside my project folder, I didn't find anything related to the tokens. Only stuff related to my models;
2. deleting it directly from the database could be another option, but I'm afraid of messing with django migrations (although it shoudn't have links with other tables anymore)

I must clarify I've already removed **rest_framework.authtoken** from my **INSTALLED_APPS**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the authtoken tables you may use django's migration command in the following way:

```
python manage.py migrate authtoken zero
```

This will revert all the migrations from the authtoken app, effectively removing the tables from the database (as long as this doesn't break any constraints).

The *zero* migration can be used with any installed django app ([see relevant django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/#reverting-migrations)).

After running the zero migration, you may remove the app from `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: Can I delete the **authtoken** files after running your command? As suggested in points **#2** and **#3** of the previous answer?

Comment: @dc_Bita98 yes, the command will delete the database tables associated with the authtoken app. You can then remove all the references from your code (INSTALLED_APPS, etc). I will update the answer to clarify : )

Comment: I think this should be the right way of proceeding, but I've previously remove **rest_framework.authtoken** from my **INSTALLED_APPS**, so when I run that command, I get the following error `CommandError: No installed app with label 'authtoken'`

Comment: Migrations can only be run for apps that are installed. The app can be removed from the INSTALLED_APPS setting after running the command.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose the first option. There are 3 steps should you do to complete uninstall `authtoken` from your Django app

1. Remove `rest_framework.authtoken` from `INSTALLED_APPS`, this action will tell your Django app to do not take any migrations file from that module
2. Remove `authtoken_token` table, if you will
3. Find the record with `authtoken` app name in table `django_migrations`, you can remove it.

Note: There are several error occurs in your code, because `authtoken` module is removed from your `INSTALLED_APPS`. My advice, backup your existing database first before you do above step

Comment: I advise anyone who read this question to also follow this answer, cause it provides other necessary steps to completely delete the app. Thank you